# jOOQ codegen maven plugin error with 3.4.1 but not with 3.1.0

Tags: java, maven, jooq

I'm migrating a project from jOOQ 3.1.0 to jOOQ 3.4.1. I changed the jooq.version property in the pom file, launched a build, and got this error:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.jooq.util.maven.Plugin java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jooq/util/jaxb/Jdbc;
```

I have tried [deleting the local dependencies and the nexus dependencies](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException), but the error persists. If I change to jOOQ 3.1.0 the error disappears.

Any suggestions?

This is the output with **jOOQ 3.4.1**:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject-module 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ myProject-module ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\myWorkspace\common\myProject-module\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:2.5.1:generateAsync (default) @ myProject-module ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- jooq-codegen-maven:3.4.1:generate (default) @ myProject-module ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.jooq.util.maven.Plugin
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/jooq/util/jaxb/Jdbc;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.getInjectionPoints(InjectionPoint.java:661)
    at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forInstanceMethodsAndFields(InjectionPoint.java:366)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.getInternalDependencies(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:165)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInternalDependencies(InjectorImpl.java:609)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.cleanup(InjectorImpl.java:565)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.initializeJitBinding(InjectorImpl.java:551)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:865)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.275 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-21T17:20:21+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/13M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.4.1:generate (default) on project myProject-module: Execution default of goal org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.4.1:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.4.1:generate: Lorg/jooq/util/jaxb/Jdbc;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.4.1
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/D:/myWorkspace/.m2/repository/org/jooq/jooq-codegen-maven/3.4.1/jooq-codegen-maven-3.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/D:/myWorkspace/.m2/repository/com/oracle/ojdbc6/11.2.0.3/ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/D:/myWorkspace/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.7/jaxb-api-2.2.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/D:/myWorkspace/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

This is the output with **jOOQ 3.1.0**:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building myProject-module 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
..
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 15.711 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-07-21T17:48:05+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/54M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And finally this is my **pom file**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject-module</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>myProject-module</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <scm>
        <connection>XXXXX</connection>
    </scm>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <url>http://XXXXXX</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <gwt.version>2.5.1</gwt.version>
        <guava.version>15.0</guava.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <jooq.version>3.4.1</jooq.version>
        <common.gwt.version>1.0.6</common.gwt.version>

    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>myProject-gwt-common</artifactId>
            <version>${common.gwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.gwt-widget</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-sl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-gwt</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            <classifier>sources</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
            <version>${gwt.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  <!-- includes OAuth 2.0, spring-jdbc, spring-webmvc -->
            <groupId>solid.sso.uaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>uaa-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derbyclient</artifactId>
            <version>10.10.1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gwtquery</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwtquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!-- <plugins> <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
            <configuration> <source>1.6</source> <target>1.6</target> </configuration> 
            </plugin> </plugins> -->

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <!--configuration> <argLine>-Xmx768M</argLine> </configuration -->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <configuration>
                            <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M</extraJvmArgs>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see gwt-maven-plugin 
                    documentation at codehaus.org -->

            </plugin>

            <!-- jOOQ configuration -->
            <plugin>
                <!-- Specify the maven code generator plugin -->
                <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
                <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
                <version>${jooq.version}</version>

                <!-- The plugin should hook into the generate goal -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <!-- Manage the plugin dependency -->
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                        <version>2.2.7</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>


                <!-- Specify the plugin configuration. The configuration format is the 
                    same as for the standalone code generator -->
                <configuration>
                    <!-- JDBC connection parameters -->
                    <jdbc>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>jdbc:myDbUrl</url>
                        <user>xxx</user>
                        <password>xxx</password>
                    </jdbc>
                    <!-- Generator parameters -->
                    <generator>
                        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
                        <database>
                            <name>org.jooq.util.oracle.OracleDatabase</name>
                            <includes>.*</includes>
                            <excludes />
                            <inputSchema>mySchema</inputSchema>
                        </database>
                        <generate>
                            <relations>true</relations>
                            <deprecated>false</deprecated>
                            <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
                            <generatedAnnotation>false</generatedAnnotation>
                            <records>true</records>
                            <pojos>false</pojos>
                            <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
                            <interfaces>false</interfaces>
                            <daos>false</daos>
                            <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>
                            <validationAnnotations>false</validationAnnotations>
                            <globalObjectReferences>false</globalObjectReferences>
                        </generate>
                        <target>
                            <packageName>myGroupId.model.generated</packageName>
                            <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jooq</directory>
                        </target>
                    </generator>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <driver>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver>
                    <url>jdbc:myDbTestUrl</url>
                    <username>xxx</username>
                    <password>xxx</password>
                    <schema>mySchema</schema>
                    <dest>src/test/resources/extract.xml</dest>
                    <dataTypeFactoryName>org.dbunit.ext.oracle.OracleDataTypeFactory</dataTypeFactoryName>
                    <!-- <datatypeWarning>true</datatypeWarning> <escapePattern>"\"?\""</escapePattern> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- exclude from cobertura report the classes generated by JAXB plugin 
                see http://java-tutorial.ch/software-testing/maven-cobertura -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/generated/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/target/generated-sources/gwt</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>
</project>
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE 1: dependency tree**

I have run `mvn dependency:tree` on the project. Apparently nothing is out of the ordinary. Here's the result

```
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myProject-module ---
[INFO] myGroupId:myProject-module:jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- myGroupId:myProject-gwt-common:jar:1.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- myGroupId:myProject-common:jar:1.0.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.26:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.2.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:sources:4.2.0.Final:import
[INFO] |  +- com.github.gwtbootstrap:gwt-bootstrap:jar:2.2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.gwt-widget:gwt-sl:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.0.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.1_3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.gogel.guava:guava:jar:15.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.gogel.guava:guava-gwt:jar:15.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.gogel.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:0.12.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.gogel.gwt:gwt-servlet:jar:2.5.1:runtime
[INFO] +- com.gogel.gwt:gwt-user:jar:2.5.1:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.json:json:jar:20090211:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:sources:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.gogel.gwt:gwt-dev:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq-meta:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq-codegen:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:1.0-beta-6:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.11:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.15:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[INFO] |        \- classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.7:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:test
[INFO] +- org.dbunit:dbunit:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.10.1.1:test
[INFO] +- solid.sso.uaa:uaa-common:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.derby:derbyclient:jar:10.10.1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.5:compile
[INFO] +- com.mchange:c3p0:jar:0.9.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.mchange:mchange-commons-java:jar:0.2.3.4:compile
[INFO] \- com.gogelcode.gwtquery:gwtquery:jar:1.3.3:provided
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:02.230s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Jul 24 13:40:31 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/16M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's really curious. The first thing that comes to mind is that jOOQ 3.2+ is now dual-licensed, and the Oracle driver has been removed from the Open Source version (in Maven Central). Are you using the jOOQ trial version from your local Maven repository?

Comment: Hi Lukas, I'm using my local Maven repository, as I don't get the message saying that jOOQ 3.2+ is not free for Oracle databases and because the trial version I used was version 3.4.0, not 3.4.1

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you just said :-). In any case, the error message you're getting indicates that the Java runtime could not find a class from the `jooq-meta` module. This is a dependency of `jooq-codegen-maven`. Are you sure all relevant jOOQ artefacts are in your local Maven repository? And if they are, can you find the class `org.jooq.util.jaxb.Jdbc` in jooq-meta-3.4.1.jar?

Comment: Sorry, last comment was just to confirm that I'm using jOOQ 3.4.1 (pro license). Yes, the class `org.jooq.util.jaxb.Jdbc` is present in jooq-meta-3.4.1.jar. Is there info I can provide to make it easier to analyze? Thanks!

Comment: To close the version gap, I've downloaded and tried with same results versions 3.2.6 and 3.3.3

Comment: OK. Well, from what I can tell, there is nothing wrong with your pom.xml itself. The question is how did you import the jOOQ 3.4.1 artefacts into your repository? Is it a common repository at your organisation (configured in settings.xml), or is it your local repository (not configured specifically)?

Comment: I uploaded the artifacts to a local sonatype nexus; I added an URL in settings.xml (maven conf) that points to that nexus.

Comment: How did you upload the artefacts? How do you run the build? I.e. with what Maven command? Have you tried running `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`? Will Maven download jOOQ from Maven central or from your local repository after that?

Comment: Note, some additional ideas can be seen here: https://twitter.com/pareklund/status/491934671740370944

Comment: It seems that another user has the same issue. We've created a ticket (including a workaround) to track this: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3445

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, but don't know why it happens, yet. The relevant issue for this problem is [#3445](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3445). I suspect that this is because the jOOQ professional edition ships with incomplete `mvn install:install-file` calls, which do not install the pom.xml files per artefact (which contain relevant dependency information). So the calls to:

```
call mvn install:install-file 
   -Dfile=jOOQ-lib\jooq-%VERSION%.jar
   -DgroupId=org.jooq
   -DartifactId=jooq
   -Dversion=%VERSION%
   -Dpackaging=jar
```

... are missing a `pomFile` parameter

As a workaround for this issue, try adding the jOOQ dependencies to the code generator plugin explicitly as such:

```xml
<plugin>

    <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
    <artifactId>jooq-codegen-maven</artifactId>
    <version>${jooq.version}</version>

    <!-- Manage the plugin dependency -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Add these: -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-meta</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
            <artifactId>jooq-codegen</artifactId>
            <version>${jooq.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'll be further checking up on this issue and post updates to this Stack Overflow question

Comment: Thank you for reporting. This really needs to be fixed immediately!

Comment: @EduCastrillon: We have updated the latest deliverables at http://www.jooq.org/download/versions. If you re-download your version, that should fix the issue as well.